# Send emails 14 days from date in cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've wrote the following code- on the homepage there is a cell (merged at the moment) where we'd put in the date. The end goal is to have the script send emails out when the current date meets 14 days later from the date in the cell.

```
function sendEmails() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email addresses")

  var hpsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Main Page-Control Plan")

  var startRow = 2; // Start at second row because the first row contains the data labels

  var numRows = 2; // Put in here the number of rows you want to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B4

  // Column A = Email Address, Column B = First Name

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {

  var row = data[i];

  var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column of selected data

  var personName = row[1]

  var currentDate = new Date(hpsheet.getRange("F6:F9").getValue());

  var fourteenDaysLater = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  console.log(fourteenDaysLater)
 
  var subject = 'Recovery schedule is due';
  
  var message ='Hi, ' +  personName  + '\n\n' + 'Recovery schedule is due. Please notify other members in this email chain if this has been done. '

  if (fourteenDaysLater < new Date()) {

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
}
}
```

I've put a daily trigger on it to run the script between 6-7am and put the date in the cell as 09/02/23, I've changed the number of days to 1 in the fourteenDaysLater variable so I could see if it worked today but I didn't get emails for some reason.

Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you parse the string to Date(), where the parsed date shows `Sat Sep 16 00:00:00 GMT+12:00 2023` in my timezone.

To make sure it parses the correct format and timezone, try the code below:

```
var timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var dateString = "09/02/23"; //replace with your cell value
var format = "dd/MM/yy"; //date format to parse
var currentDate = Utilities.parseDate(dateString,timezone,format);

var fourteenDaysLater = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```